# Microsoft Solver Foundation - how to use function as constraint?

Tags: c#, constraint-programming, ms-solver-foundation

I'm trying to find a solution to a problem using Microsoft Solver Foundation in C# and I'm having trouble setting up all the constraints I need. My basic model is I have a list of bays and I need to load each bay so that the total of all the bays is maximised. I'm currently doing it like this

```
var solver = SolverContext.GetContext();
var model = solver.CreateModel();
var decisions = 
    bays.Select(b => new Decision(Domain.IntegerNonnegative, "B"+b.bay.getShortName()));
model.AddDecisions(decisions.ToArray());

foreach (BayPositionLoading bay in bays)
{
    model.AddConstraint(
            "B" + bay.bay.getShortName() + "Cons",
            model.Decisions
                 .First(d => d.Name == "B" + bay.bay.getShortName()) <= bay.bay.maxLoad);
}
```

What I really would like to be able to do is add a constraint that a certain function returns true. The function would be something like this

```
public bool isValid (List<Bay> bays)
{
    return blah;
}
```

But I can't figure out how to create the list of bays to pass to this function. I would like to do something like but this keeps throwing an exception when I say ToDouble or GetDouble.

```
foreach(Bay b in bays)
{
    var dec= model.Decisions.First(it => it.Name == "B" + bay.bay.getShortName());
    b.actualLoad = dec.ToDouble(); // Or GetDouble
}
model.AddConstraint("func", isValid(bays) == true);
```

Can anyone suggest how this can be done? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the math provided with OML language only, I do not think custom functions like you try to use are supported in MSF.

Comment: I believe this stems from the implicit requirements of the simplex algorithm. There are other Solvers that do support reusing custom functions (for example [OptaPlanner](http://www.optaplanner.org/)), but they use other optimization algorithms (such as metaheuristics).

Comment: MSF is not limited to simplex algorithm.